# PHP/JSON - how to import name of stdClass Object?

Tags: php, json

how to import name of stdClass object to database?

JSON object contains:

```
[items] => stdClass Object
                    ( 
  [bigitems] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [nameitem1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [height] => 100
                                [width] => 137
            )
            [nameitem2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [height] => 506
                                [width] => 678
            )
            [nameitem3] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [height] => 330
                                [width] => 845
            )
            [nameitem3] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [height] => 793
                                [width] => 788
            )
        )
)
```

I want store into database only value nameitem1 - nameitem4

Nameitems is for example - box,case - different word no numerical range
Bigitems Is a NUMBER

```
    [items] => stdClass Object
                    ( 
  [4856985254] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [box] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [height] => 100
                                [width] => 137
            )
            [case] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [height] => 506
                                [width] => 678
            )
            [paper] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [height] => 330
                                [width] => 845
            )
        )
```

for this operation i try use this script. script working but missing store part

```
function wwwResponse($url, $isUrl = true)
{
  if ($isUrl && !ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
    throw new Exception('allow_url_fopen = Off');
  }

  $content = file_get_contents($url);
  if ($isUrl) {
    $status_code = substr($http_response_header[0], 9, 3);
    if ($status_code != 200) {
      throw new Exception('Got status code ' . $status_code . ' expected 200');
    }
  }

  $json = json_decode($content);
  if (!$json) {
    throw new Exception('Response contained an invalid JSON response');
  }

  if ($json->status != 'ok') {
    throw new Exception($json->status_code);
  }

  return $json;
}

// --------------------------DB------------------------------- 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "baze", "xxxxxxx");
 mysql_select_db("baze");
//------------------------------------------------------------

    try {
    $json = wwwResponse($url);
        print_r ($json);
    }
  catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
echo "<pre>\n";
}
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$items = json_decode(json_encode($obj->items), true);
$names = array_keys((Array) $items['4856985254']);

// will return Array("nameitem1","nameitem2","nameitem3")
```

Comment: @Hunt3r ups i completely forgotten about this phpwtf (you can't access numeric property of stdclass). you can use dirty trick instead (see my answer). so it might be better for you if you decode whole object into array (see user2868760 answer)

Comment: right this is working. when i type  echo  $names[2] i got right value. Great thanks you

Answer (score 1):

If it helps you can decode JSON this way to get an array instead of STD object:

```
$result = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

Anyway you can do this:

```
foreach ($data as $d) {
    foreach ($d as $actual) {
        //echo stuff here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$vars = get_object_vars($items->bigitems);
foreach ($vars as $key => $value)
... insert $key ....
```